# Symfony2 Security token storage is breaking my project

Tags: security, symfony

Got this security config:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
            use_referer:  true
            require_previous_session: true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            success_handler: authentication_handler
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   "%domain%"
            name:     "REMEMEMBERME"
```

When im going to open my project in production envoirment it crashes.

```
[2015-09-24 18:53:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at
[2015-09-24 18:53:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at
[2015-09-24 18:53:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at
[2015-09-24 18:53:26] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." at
```

It pass in all routes of the project.

## Additional info

*I could see only breaks when asset displays an image. That is, in the view that no images are included is not broken, which if it breaks.*

## More info

This is the function that is causing the error:

```
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')
```

If i comment the function, the project works fine.

Comment: Did you clear prod cache?

Comment: Like 300 times, ill add some info to the main post

Comment: Can you recall the solution to this? Im hitting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your firewall for your urls.

Some examples:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I have the set. I hit the firewall rule only because I think it's the only thing that produces the error.

Comment: Can you provide more information (your debug stack or where exactly the problem was, can you login,...)?

Comment: The problem arises on all routes of my project. Which tells me that it's a problem somewhere listener is either configuration. The question is  where.
i have listeners to KernelRequest, and to some events FOSUserBundle

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ?  if so can you please share how you did it i have the same issue :(